# jersey/jackson POST to spring mvc - bad request

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

REST in Spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = {"application/json"}, consumes = {"application/json"}) {
        public String createSomething(@RequestBody Simple simple) {
            return "";
}
```

And my entity class:

```
public class Simple {
    private String name;
 // plus default constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Consuming REST with jersey 2:

```
WebTarget webTarget =  clientBuilder.build().target("http://localhost:8080/spring/something");
webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(new Simple("example"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);
```

This is working fine. But once I declare *Simple* as:

```
public class Simple extends AnotherClass { .. }
```

I always get 400 Bad request. Even if *AnotherClass* has no attributes at all.

Comment: provide your another class. Better enable debug logging and provide logs.

Comment: AnotherClass has only a default constructor for now. That's all. Same problem. extending with _anything_ causes this problem.

Comment: I can see that your DTO has non-default constructors: `new Simple("example")`. Try removing all constructors that are not default.